# dynamic type based on existing in typescript

Tags: typescript

For a given object like:

```
class Product {
  constructor(
    public metadata: Metadata,
    public topic: Topic,
    public title = 'empty'
  ) {}
  ...
}
```

I want to create an interface:

```
interface State<T> {
}
```

such that TypeScript ensures that a `product: State<Product>` has the same structure as Product but its matching leaf-level properties are boolean. So `product` is supposed to have a title property of type boolean.

---

I had a look at the readonly example at [mapped-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) but in this case I probably need a composite:

```
interface State<T> {
  [p in keyof T]: typeof T[p] === 'object' ? State<T[p]> : boolean;
}
```

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, your syntax is off, you need to use a `type` not an `interface`, and `typeof T[p] === 'object'` is written as `T[p] extends object`

```
class Metadata {
  constructor(
    public key = 'empty',
    public value = 'empty'
  ) { }
}
class Topic {
  constructor(
    public name = 'empty'
  ) { }
}
class Product {
  constructor(
    public metadata: Metadata[],
    public topic: Topic,
    public title = 'empty'
  ) { }

}

type State<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? State<T[P]> : boolean
}
let o: State<Product> = {
  title: true,
  topic: {
    name: true
  },
  metadata: [
    { key: true, value: false }
  ]
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Metadata%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20key%20%3D%20'empty'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20value%20%3D%20'empty'%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Topic%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%20%3D%20'empty'%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Product%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20metadata%3A%20Metadata%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20topic%3A%20Topic%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20title%20%3D%20'empty'%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20object%20%3F%20State%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%20%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20o%3A%20State%3CProduct%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20title%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20topic%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20metadata%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20true%2C%20value%3A%20false%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: sounds promising, i'll have a look at it

Comment: for some reason compile breaks at extends keyword: TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: @RobyRodriguez what version of TS are you using ? Code was tested on 3.4 in the playground, I will add a link

Comment: "typescript": "~2.7.2" :(

Comment: @RobyRodriguez yeah .. that will not work, you might get something working on 2.8 (arrays will be an issue, proper array handling in mapped types was added in 3.2 or 3.1 I belive) but 2.7 does not have conditional types

Comment: i see.. one more question though - in the conditional where you check 'extends object' can i check for other types, i.e. exclude some object types?.... say any object except `SelectItem`

Comment: @RobyRodriguez Sure conditional types are very flexible you can check `extends` any type you want. `T[P] extends SelectItem ? State<T[P]> : boolean` should be fine. But don't forget TS types are structurally matched

Answer (score 0):

Use type instead of an interface:

```
type State<T> = { [P in keyof T]: boolean };
```

Comment: While not 100% clear, I think OP wants to map a nested structure with primitive properties being `boolean`

Comment: Oh, I have misunderstood then. "...but its matching leaf-level properties are boolean.", you're right. Well then he has your answer. :)